# Переработать код в стиле ООП

Tags: python, ооп

Нужно переработать код в стиле ООП, с ООП знаком очень мало и трудно дается. Как можно переработать код чтобы он был в стиле ООП?

Исходный код:

```
print("УДИВИТЕЛЬНО, ЕСЛИ ПРАВИЛЬНО ОТВЕЧАТЬ, БУДЕТ БОЛЬШЕ БАЛОВ!!!")
w=0
def qr(ot):
    global w
    if ot==answer:
        print("yes")
        w+=1
        print('Вы набрали: ',w)
    else:
        print("no")
        print('Вы набрали: ',w)

print("Почему в 1998 году фирменный знак компании  Nestle - птица и три птенца в гнезде - лишился одного птенца ?")
print("a) Оказалось, что такой же логотип пренадлежит другой компании")
print("b) В среднестатистической семье в западных странах стало два ребенка вместо трёх")
print("c) Один из акционеров продал свою долю")

answer = input ("Ответ: ")
qr("b")

print("Почему во время первой мировой войны в окопах держали кошек?")
print("a) В окопах было много мышей")
print("b) Они предупреждали о газовой атаке")
print("c) Они напоминали о доме")

answer = input ("Ответ: ")
qr("b")

print("Почему в Московском метро в одних случаях станции объявляются мужским голосом, а в других - женским?")
print("a) Для удобства ориентирования глухих пасажиров")
print("b) Для удобства ориентирования слепых пасажиров")
print("c) Для удобства ориентирования немых пасажиров")

answer = input ("Ответ: ")
qr("b")

print("Почему немецкий город Баден-Баден имеет двойное название?")
print("a) Он стоит у подножия одноименной горы с двумя вершинами")
print("b) Чтобы не путали с Австрийским и швейцарским Баденом")
print("c) Его основали братья Баден")

answer = input ("Ответ: ")
qr("b")

print("Почему 4-го июня 1888 года Конгресс штата Нью-Йорк отменил казнь через повешение ?")
print("a) Ее сменила казнь на электрическом стуле")
print("b) Прервалась династия профессиональных палачей")
print("c) Из-за низкой эффективности")

answer = input ("Ответ: ")
qr("a")
print("Отличная игра!")
```

Написал класс:

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, answer, correct):
        self.answer = answer
        self.correct = correct
```

Но как все это привести к нормальному виду, не понимаю

Comment: Еще у Question можно список вариантов ответа добавить

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Немного переделал код, сохранив логику.

Пример:

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, text: str, correct: str, variants: list):
        self.text = text
        self.correct = correct
        self.variants = variants

    def ask(self) -> bool:
        print(self.text)
        for x in self.variants:
            print('  ' + x)

        answer = input("Ответ: ")
        return answer == self.correct


question_list = [
    Question(
        "Почему в 1998 году фирменный знак компании  Nestle - птица и три птенца в гнезде - лишился одного птенца?",
        correct='b',
        variants=[
            "a) Оказалось, что такой же логотип принадлежит другой компании",
            "b) В среднестатистической семье в западных странах стало два ребенка вместо трёх",
            "c) Один из акционеров продал свою долю",
        ]
    ),
    Question(
        "Почему во время первой мировой войны в окопах держали кошек?",
        correct='b',
        variants=[
            "a) В окопах было много мышей",
            "b) Они предупреждали о газовой атаке",
            "c) Они напоминали о доме",
        ]
    ),
    Question(
        "Почему в Московском метро в одних случаях станции объявляются мужским голосом, а в других - женским?",
        correct='b',
        variants=[
            "a) Для удобства ориентирования глухих пассажиров",
            "b) Для удобства ориентирования слепых пассажиров",
            "c) Для удобства ориентирования немых пассажиров",
        ]
    ),
]


print("УДИВИТЕЛЬНО, ЕСЛИ ПРАВИЛЬНО ОТВЕЧАТЬ, БУДЕТ БОЛЬШЕ БАЛЛОВ!!!")
w = 0

for question in question_list:
    if question.ask():
        print("yes")
        w += 1
    else:
        print("no")

    print('Вы набрали:', w)
    print()

print("Отличная игра!")
```

Comment: Ну тогда уж ввести ещё один класс Game, который будет рулить всем процессом игры и вести подсчёт очков.

Comment: @Xander, а еще можно в `Question` явно ключ варианта привязывать к варианту: `{"a": "В окопах было много мышей"}`, а при составлении вопроса подставлять шаблоном: `f"  {...}) {...}"`, а при получении неправильного ответа ругаться, что такого варианта нет и предлагать ввести правильный (смотрим в `variants.keys()`), и подобное можно продолжать долго :) Идея с Game неплохая, к месту, но не хотел усложнять код лишними сущностями. Думаю, автор вопроса понял идею и сможет сам при желании внедрить больше вспомогательных классов :)

Comment: Вообще по логике вопрос не может быть правильным, это свойство ответа (ответов, если такое разрешено) в конкретном вопросе.

Comment: @Jazzis, не часто один и тот же ответ может подходить для разных вопросов, поэтому не вижу смысла создавать больше сущностей :)